# pgbouncer - closing because: unexpected response from login query

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer

My pgbouncer.ini file:

```
[databases]
* = host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 auth_user=pgbouncer_auth

[pgbouncer]
listen_port = 6432
listen_addr = 127.0.0.1
auth_type = md5
auth_file = ./pgbouncer_user.txt
auth_user = pgbouncer_auth
auth_query = SELECT usename, passwd FROM user_search($1)
logfile = pgbouncer.log
pidfile = pgbouncer.pid
admin_users = aakashverma, postgres
```

The command I am using

`psql -p 6432 -U aakashverma -d postgres`

Server's debug info:

```
2021-05-24 09:52:53.001 India Standard Time [19124] LOG S-028fcb48: postgres/pgbouncer_auth@127.0.0.1:5432 closing because: unexpected response from login query (age=0s)
2021-05-24 09:52:53.015 India Standard Time [19124] LOG C-028c57a0: postgres/(nouser)@127.0.0.1:56255 closing because: unexpected response from login query (age=0s)
2021-05-24 09:52:53.027 India Standard Time [19124] WARNING C-028c57a0: postgres/(nouser)@127.0.0.1:56255 pooler error: unexpected response from login query
2021-05-24 09:53:47.414 India Standard Time [19124] LOG stats: 0 xacts/s, 0 queries/s, in 0 B/s, out 4 B/s, xact 0 us, query 0 us, wait 2467 us
2021-05-24 09:54:47.409 India Standard Time [19124] LOG stats: 0 xacts/s, 0 queries/s, in 0 B/s, out 0 B/s, xact 0 us, query 0 us, wait 0 us
2021-05-24 09:55:47.411 India Standard Time [19124] LOG stats: 0 xacts/s, 0 queries/s, in 0 B/s, out 0 B/s, xact 0 us, query 0 us, wait 0 us
```

Where am I going wrong? The `postgres/(nouser)` seems to throw some hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the issue was that I was trying to log in as one of the `admin_users`(aakashverma)  but I hadn't mentioned them in `pgbouncer_user.txt` file - my `auth_file`. I only had my `auth_user` in that file initially.

Mentioning them in each line in the file (just the username was enough as I'm using `auth_query`) like so

```
"pgbouncer_auth" "md58b235183e543896e3521c8a29a2272e1"
"aakashverma"
"postgres"
```